# Detect collision of a UIImageView with ANY object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I am writing an application where there is a central `UIImageView` and many other images are generated dynamically and move around the screen. I want to know when the central `UIImageView` collides with ANY of the dynamically generated objects. I know there is the `CGRectIntersectsRect`, but I have to specify the other object and this is not possible since there are many of them. Instead, I want to know when a collision happens with ANY object.

Comment: Could you not put the event on the other objects (subclass/create a delegate) and have them listen for intersecting with your one central UIImageView?

Comment: I'm not an expert with Core Graphics...but I'm guessing there's no "didCollideWithAnyObject" method....but I'm curious about this problem too so I hope somebody comes up with something cool!

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the elements are subclasses of UIView, you may be able to check for intersection with all elements using this code:

```
//imageView represents your central UIImageView
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame, view.frame) && ![view isEqual: imageView])
    {
        //Implement relevant code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at UIKit Dynamics. Here is the awesome [Tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/collision-detection-with-uikit-dynamics-in-ios-7). Also Refer [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikit_framework/_index.html)